Disable Onscreen keyboard on 2-in-1 laptop
I have an LG gram 2-in-1 laptop running Ubuntu 24.04. Whenever the screen is touched, the onscreen keyboard appears, [EDIT: it happens when focus is in an input field; whether you touch the screen in that input field or you use a mouse or the trackpad to put the focus in that input field. It does not happen when touching any arbitrary place on the screen] blocking 1/2 the screen. Ironically, touching the 'hide' down-arrow on the OSK does not work, one has to use the mouse for that to be recognized. I want to be able to use only the physical keyboard for text input. I've tried the older extension that blocks 'caribou', but that doesn't work. How do I completely disable or remove the OSK? Where is the executable for this "functionality" so that I can just remove it? Any other ideas on how to kill the OSK? I rarely or never use the device in tablet mode and would rather not have any OSK if it means it takes over my laptop every time I touch the screen [EDIT: accidentally touch an input field].

It is described in the ubuntu documentation, on which this answer it's based.

Open the Activities overview and start typing Accessibility.

Click on Accessibility to open the panel.

Click on the Typing section.

Switch off the Screen Keyboard.



Sorry, I should have delineated more of the obvious things that do not work. That setting does nothing on this laptop. It is already switched off.

BTW, immediately above where the official documentation gives those 4 steps to switch off or on the OSK, it says, "The on-screen keyboard is automatically enabled if you use a touchscreen" Getting around this is the goal.

Which version of block caribou extension did you use, where from and how did you install it? I only ask as I use a version which says it's compatible with Gnome 45, and even though I am on 22.04.1 LTS with Gnome 46 it does still help with this situation (although it does not completely disable the onscreen keyboard).
Without the extension, pressing screen anywhere brings up the OSK. With the extension the OSK only appears if you press on something which allows text input (e.g. an input field, browser address bar, terminal etc)
So not really a full answer to your question but may help a bit and I am following this to see if you get a full answer. On mine (a touchscreen HDMI/USB monitor rather than a laptop) the down/hide OSK button does nothing too, which I could never understand. I have to click away from an input field to hide the OSK.
I went here:
https://github.com/lxylxy123456/cariboublocker/releases
Downloaded the assets zip version closest to my Gnome version (currently 45.zip
Then install with:
gnome-extensions install ~/Downloads/45.zip --force

(I had to reboot for it to take effect and confusingly the extension is always called "Block Caribou 36" regardless of the version downloaded).

I've installed the 45 release (thanks for those brief and clear install instructions) and it has no effect. By the way, on my laptop, I do not get the OSK whenever the screen is touched, as I idiotically said in my original post, it comes up, as you state, whenever the cursor or focus is in an input field. It does this whether or not you actually touch the screen; you can use the trackpad to put the cursor in an input field and the OSK shows up. When you open a new tab in a browser, the cursor and focus are automatically in the address bar, so the OSK pops up every time you open a new tab.
